# Can yantras be used a remedies for Doshas in horoscopes and nakshatras?

Tags: astrology, nakshatra, yantra

Is it possible to use yantras to resolve Doshas in horoscopes and nakshatras and if so:

1.Is it common practice to use yantras as a remedy?

2.For e.g in the case of a graha dosha,mantras are usually chanted to pacify the graha devta. But how do yantras resolve Doshas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Yantras are the sources of energy and it will be activated if we recite a certain mantra constantly. Once it is activated, it will start transmitting its powers to the surroundings. It makes a impact to a human based on his capacity. It is again proportional to his spiritual capacity where he can intake the power. It is a vast subject to get a complete knowledge of Yantra.

Worshipping God/Goddess using Yantra is one of the best way to attain salvation. It is strictly adhered in all temples. We can keep some Yantras in home as well for worshiping under some restrictions.

The most popular yantras for worshiping in home are Shri Yantra(Yantra Raja), Vasthu Yantra, Navagraha Yantra. Now a days people started having yantras of Grama devate, goddess Mahalakshmi, Ganesha, etc.

Proper worshiping of Yantra will be remedy for get rid of all planetary doshas. Its ultimate goal is the person should attain enlightenment.

It is not recommended to have yantra as pendant/ring in one's body. Many people are now a days misleading our spiritual and religious values by introducing such practices. One should keep only ShriYantra with restrictions as same as Rudraksha.

In Shivism, Rudraksha is the symbol of Lord Shiva. In Shaktam, Shri Yantra is the symbol of Goddess Lalitha Tripura Sundari. If one knows about Shri Yantra, we come to know that it is a form of Lord Shiva and Shakthi.

To get rid of any kind of doshas, Worshiping Shri Yantra is the best remedy. It not only resolves the problem also tunes the life of the person to attain the righteous path.

I will add more details about Shri Yantra in personal blog soon. Stay tuned..

https://rkkrishnaa.in/

Answer (score 1):

The word Yantra basically means "a device". The use of device varies according to its structure and shape. There are many types of yantras and the answer for your question is yes to some extent. I'll rather Ans your two questions separately.

1. By 'common' if you mean, is it the only possible common remedy, then the ans is no. Now see yantra and mantras are generally interconnected, and for the proper functioning of yantra, a mantra is used. Now, a person cant use the mantra or yantra just from listening or seeing it from someone. That's wrong. His holiness Shankarachrya of Kamakoti peetham, Sri Chandrashekarendra Saraswati paramacharya himself condemned such illiterate and vauge use of yantras, tantras, mantras and saligrams. These objects can bend the energy field around us anyway. If you don't know how to use them they will cause more harm than good. That, doesn't mean you should not use yantra, mantras etc., but to use them you first need to invest so part of your time i.e., find a apt guru/ wait until a apt guru comes to you with experience in using the mantra, yantra and, tantra associated with these. Not the gurus who take money in exchange for teaching you but the ones who really do vidya dana and give you the mantra. The guru will then have to explain and tutor you personally at least once all the rules and regulations associated. Do's and Don't etc. If you can do all this then take the mantra and yantra. Else, don't do it.

2.When you connect the mantra with the yantra properly and then, use the yantra, will bend the respective natural forces in such a way the karma that you need to experience now will be shifted to some other time in the future or some type of yantras destroy the karma. The above depends on the lakshana/character of that specific yantra and your mental power and determination.

**But in the present times its generally its difficult to find such an experienced guru. Even if we find such a guru, its difficult for us to engage and give so much of time because the process takes a long time time to learn and perfect. Hence, its best to follow vratas/ if possible nitya-agnihotram. **

***EXTRA INFO
These days many people who want to do yantra puja directly buy a srichakra and start doing aradhana. This not only wrong but dangerous too. For sometime, maybe as of now your previous karma might stop it from showing effect but as soon as that gets over, it will strike like vajra if you don't know how to use it, because, if you play with potent energy that's what happens. First you need to be trained in sri-vidya upasana and navavaran puja. Then only you can satisfy the srichakra if activated. But to properly master these it will take years without a person who himself isnt trained in it. Because when you do puja to sri chakra, you not only do it to lalitambika who is sri-vidya devata but 112 other godesses too. Over that srichakra also is associated with the the kundalini. So, its best not to indulge into it without knowing about it properly. ***

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.